# In depth Ruby Gem development resources (book, video, sites)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, distributed-programming

I'm writing my first Gem for a Rails project, and looking for in depth information about this topic i have found nothing at all.

I'm not looking "how to build a gem", but a relevant developer guide or resource on the topic (distributed programming with Ruby and so on).

I expect if someone have good reference material ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubygems aren't related to distributed programming.

Can you please provide more details about what you're after, if you aren't asking a duplicate question? Related questions within Stack Overflow include:

- [Gotchas for writing rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616007/gotchas-for-writing-rubygems)
- [Ruby : How to write a gem ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194547/ruby-how-to-write-a-gem)
- [What are the steps needed to create and publish a rubygem of your own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120191/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-and-publish-a-rubygem-of-your-own)
- [What is the modern way to structure a ruby gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307209/what-is-the-modern-way-to-structure-a-ruby-gem)

(I know this is more of a comment than an answer, but it's too big to fit in the comments section)

Comment: Thanks, really what i wanted is on best practices and pure ruby code knowledge.

I was looking for a in-depth on coding a gem, not just building it (patterns, best practices, etc.) but i found my question is very trivial now.

I think i have my question answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd not bother with jeweler anymore.  Bundler gives you most of the tools you need including an initial gem generator command `bundle gem GEMNAME` (as of Bundler 1.0.0RC4) and the latest rubygems lets you `gem push` for publishing.

I've also just started playing around with building my own gems, following along with the Bundler roadmap has helped me out a lot.

Read the [gemspec ref](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20) to understand what's needed of you there, and really I've just been browsing the source of lots of gems that I know are written by reputable ruby developers (ie. mongoid, bundler etc)

Also keep in mind that distributed programming doesn't really have anything to do with Rubygems (though gems can of course facilitate that).  Yes these gems are/can be shared/distributed, but the concept of 'distributed computing' is far different from this, namely sharing the data and functions of your system across multiple nodes, servers, etc...  Since rubygems is just a means by which you might achieve distributed computing, you might want to re-word your question if that's what your real concern is.

Comment: Thanks, really what i wanted is on best practices and pure ruby code knowledge. I think i have my question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this?

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/book/1

Comment: Thanks, really what i wanted is on best practices and pure ruby code knowledge. I think i have my question answered.

Answer (score 0):

jeweler is a package helper for creating gems
http://technicalpickles.com/posts/craft-the-perfect-gem-with-jeweler/

http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler

Comment: Thanks, really what i wanted is on best practices and pure ruby code knowledge. I think i have my question answered.

(BTW i'm using Jeweler, it work like a charm)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one as well http://guides.rubygems.org/.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a book

> Build a ruby gem

written by Brandon Hilkert http://brandonhilkert.com/books/build-a-ruby-gem